# Piecewise function with integer conditions

Tags: piecewise

I'm trying to define (and plot) a piecewise function with the following structure:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) & nT \leq x \leq \frac{2n+1}{2}T\\
                      -g(x) & \frac{2n+1}{2}T \leq x \leq (n+1)T
         \end{cases}$$

where `n` is an integer, `n >= 0` and `T` is a constant.

The idea is that it cycles between positive and negative after a full period is complete.

My attempt was:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{
     {g[x], (n T <= x <= ((2 n + 1)/2) T) && Element[n, Integers] && (n >= 0)},
     {-g[x], (((2 n + 1)/2) T <= x <= (n + 1) T) && Element[n, Integers] && (n >= 0)}}]
```

But when I try a test value for `x` in `f[x]` it shows `n` in the conditions for the output, so it seems to not get past the conditions. I believe plotting fails for this reason too.

I have never tried to use `Integers` in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Have you specified a value for `T` ?

Comment: Sektor: T is specified. Patrick Stevens: Okay, thank you. Using `Floor[x/T]` instead of `n` worked. `f[x_] := Piecewise[{{g[x], Floor[x/T] T <= x <= ((2 Floor[x/T] + 1)/2) T}, {-g[x], ((2 Floor[x/T] + 1)/2) T <= x <= (Floor[x/T] + 1) T}}]` I'm not exactly sure how I would simplify the second condition. belisarius: Thank you, I can see that your version works.

Comment: It won't let me accept an answer either, I think because I was not properly signed in originally when I posted the question. Apparently I can comment now though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you haven't told `Piecewise` that `n` can be arbitrary, so Mathematica thinks it's constant. You'd be better off defining `n` as `Floor[x/T]` for the first comparison, rather than asking Mathematica to find an `n` such that the definition holds (or prove that `n` doesn't exist).

It looks like you could simplify the second condition to `True`, by the way: `Piecewise` checks the pieces in order, so there's no need to give a complicated final condition.

Answer (score 8):

A way following your line of thought:

```
T = Pi;
g[x_] := Sin@x
f[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[
     {{g[x] , Quiet@Resolve@Exists[n, n ∈ Integers && (n + 1/2)T <= x <= (n + 1)T]}},
      -g[x]]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would do it this way instead:

```
Plot[-g[x] SquareWave[x/T], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And from there you can get an equivalent Piecewise form:

```
PiecewiseExpand[-g[x] SquareWave[x/T]]
```

$$\begin{cases}
 -g(x) & 0\leq (\frac{x}{T} \bmod 1)<\frac{1}{2} \\
 g(x) & \text{True}
\end{cases}$$